# Linux 32 bit disassembly has call instructions to next byte

Tags: linux, gcc, x86, 32bit-64bit, disassembly

I'm creating a driver for 32 and 64 bit Linux OS. One of the requirements is that all of the code needs to be self contained with no call outs. On 64-bit I've no issues, but on 32-bit GCC seems to add a call instruction to the next byte. After searching a bit I found this link:

http://forum.soft32.com/linux/Strange-problem-disassembling-shared-lib-ftopict439936.html

Is there a way to disable this on 32-bit Linux?

Example:
32 bit disassembly:

```
<testfunc>:
0: push %ebp
1: mov  %esp, %ebp
3: call 4 <test_func+0x4>
<...some operation on ebx as mentioned in the link above>
```

64 bit disassebmly:

```
<testfunc>:
    0: push %rbp
    1: mov  %rsp, %rbp
    3: <...no call here>
```

There is no call in the "testfunc" at all. Even then why is 32-bit compiler adding these "call" instructions? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to disable anything, these calls are used to calculate PIC base/GOT address on i386 and they *are* "self contained" since they don't refer to any external function.

Comment: By "self contained" you mean the call does not do anything? If I step through the code, I see that the call actually jumps to an offset location way outside of my EIP and then executes certain instructions. Then it returns to my function. I don't want this behavior and I'm trying to disable this reference to GOT. Any inputs if it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing in 32-bit disassembly may be a way to make the code position-independent. Remember that `call` pushes onto the stack the return address, which is equal `eip`+constant? In 64-bit mode there is `rip`-relative addressing. In 32-bit there isn't. So this call may be simulate that instruction-pointer-relative addressing.

Comment: If thats true 32bit PIC is an awesome hack.

Comment: To add to this, if you inspect the relocation entries, these are probably the places that get address fixups during loading, so the final instruction doesn't end up being `call 4`, because the `4` is replaced by the actual address of the destination by ld.so when the library/binary is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Yes, it's related to PIC. When I added -fPIC to compile flags, here's what I get. It is trying to refer to Global Offset Table.
`<testfunc>:
0: push %ebp
1: mov  %esp, %ebp
3: call 4 <testfunc+0x4>
    R_386_PC32   __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
9: add    $0x2,%ebx
                        b: R_386_GOTPC  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
f: call   *0x0(%ebx)
                        11: R_386_GOT32 mcount`

Answer (score 0):

This call instruction to the next byte is coming from function profiling for "gprof" tool. I was able to get rid of these "call" instruction by removing the "-pg" option from compilation.

Since it was a driver, this was being picked up from Linux kernel config - CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER.